# SharePoint Onlie REST Api LookUp query

Tags: ajax, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-api

I am trying to construct a SharePoint online query. Some of the columns are 
LookUp columns. I Want to get the description from the column `uQmsParent`that originates from the  list I want the description from. The column is called "uQmsDescription". I have googled and found a lot of answers. But none of there solutions worked for me.

The query:

`_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Processobjekt')/items?$select=Title,Id,uQmsDescription,uQmsOrder,uQmsType,uQmsBgColor,uQmsArea/Id,uQmsParent/Id,uQmsParent/Title,uQmsResponsible/Title,uQmsResponsible/uQmsName&$expand=uQmsArea,uQmsParent,uQmsResponsible&$filter=uQmsParent/Id eq '" + processItemId + "'&$orderby=uQmsOrder asc"`

The id and title I can get with no effort. but when I add uQmsParent/uQmsDescription to the select query I get this error `The question in the uQmsParent/uQmsDescription field is not valid.`

This is how the query look like generating the error:

`_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Processobjekt')/items?$select=Title,Id,uQmsDescription,uQmsOrder,uQmsType,uQmsBgColor,uQmsArea/Id,uQmsParent/Id,uQmsParent/Title,uQmsParent/uQmsDescription, uQmsResponsible/Title,uQmsResponsible/uQmsName&$expand=uQmsArea,uQmsParent,uQmsResponsible&$filter=uQmsParent/Id eq '" + processItemId + "'&$orderby=uQmsOrder asc"`

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you query is wrong, you are not getting the value you want in the $expand parameter.

It should be Something like:

$select=Title,Id,uQmsDescription,uQmsOrder,uQmsType,uQmsBgColor,uQmsArea/Id,uQmsParent/Id,uQmsParent/Title,uQmsParent/uQmsDescription, uQmsResponsible/Title,uQmsResponsible/uQmsName&$expand=uQmsArea/Title,uQmsParent/Title,uQmsResponsible/Id

Here is very well explained how to work with lookups:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/35796.sharepoint-2013-using-rest-api-for-selecting-filtering-sorting-and-pagination-in-sharepoint-list.aspx